# MySQL Database Unique Column Names

Tags: php, mysql

I have written myself a PHP script to help manage a small squad of 10 members. This script current connects to a database and updates weekly updating any rank and power change. However I want to expand this and in a new table, have all the power gained kept in a separate column instead of adding it all up.

The only way I can think of doing this is by using the below code to create the column and changing the name for each.

```
ALTER TABLE `power gained` ADD timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AFTER name;
```

So my question is, can I create columns making sure their name is unique, OR is it possible to set a column name to the timestamp as that would save me a column.

I'd like to also make it clear I am using mysql_ functions as this is on my local system, not vulnerable to attacks and I am not stupid enough to make mistakes.

Comment: no. you don't create more columns to store the "same but at different time" data. you create a child table and store your times/values/userIDs there.

Comment: @MarcB I don't want to make things complicated. After a while, using your method I would end up with so many tables...

Comment: 1. See normalisation.

Comment: no, you end up with ONE table. with your method, you end up with a bazillion columns, most of which would always be empty, and have truly STUPID names like `2014-08-15 09:23:13`. how would you **EVER** find those column names without having to parse the table structure every time you need to look something up? With a single sub-table, you can do ultra-simply stuff like `select sum(power) from powerups where userID=Foo and timestamp between '2014-06-01' and '2014-06-30'`.

Comment: @MarcB Without knowing what I'm doing, please don't suggest these things. Timestamps as titles WILL work.

Comment: I don't need to know what you're doing to know that it's **NOT** a good idea. Go ahead and do it however you want, but then don't come back here to complain when it turns out to be a nightmare to support or extend.

Comment: @Spedwards - You should really listen to MarcB's advice here, any other way would be stupid. You only need one child table, with userid and powergained, then you just fill that like user 1 gained 5, you can then sum these in your main table

Comment: @dave I don't think I was clear. For each user, I would like to keep track of each separate power gain. So each week I need a new column to accompany that. I do not wish to overwrite the old one.

Comment: @Spedwards Why would you need a new column? You could just have a timestamp column and in your query just return results from the last 7 days

Answer (score 3):

***Use normalisation.***

Split the users and the power into two difference tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_power` (
  `user_id` smallint(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `total_power` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `power` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` smallint(1) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `power_increase` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Update users_power`;

CREATE TRIGGER `Update users_power` AFTER INSERT ON `power` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE `users_power` AS `UP`
    SET `UP`.`total_power` = `UP`.`total_power` + NEW.`power_increase`
    WHERE `UP`.`user_id` = NEW.`user_id`;
END
```

And then to look up, do something like;

```
SELECT `power` AS total_power
FROM users_power
WHERE users_power.`user_id` = 1
```

And your structure would look something like;

```
select * from power where user_id = 1;
+----+---------+---------------------+----------------+
| id | user_id | time                | power_increase |
+----+---------+---------------------+----------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2014-08-7 17:04:06  |              5 |
|  2 |       1 | 2014-08-15 17:04:31 |             15 |
+----+---------+---------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set

select * from users_power where user_id = 1;
+---------+------+-------------+
| user_id | name | total_power |
+---------+------+-------------+
|       1 | joe  |          21 |
+---------+------+-------------+
1 row in set
```

## Edits

- Added trigger to automatically update total power when a record is inserted into `power`

Answer (score -3):

Haven't yet tested this but I think I have found a way I can do this in a way that I understand (which is the most important part).

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `power gained` ADD `$now` VARCHAR(22) AFTER name");
// ...
mysql_query("UPDATE `power gained` (`$now`) VALUES($gained) WHERE id = $i");
```

I'm not looking to extract the data from the database as I can access it just by going to localhost/phpmyadmin and I'm not going to ever need to extract it.

Comment: Still, adding an extra column a pretty bad way to go about it. What if, in the future, you want to extract it? This approach isn't future-proof.

Comment: @hd. I can still extract this easily... The column names are just dates for every Friday. So `2014-08-08`, `2014-08-15`, `2014-08-22` and so on.